# Make a clickable dropdown that gets the values and places them in a table JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is a validation check that already works i have a name,Email and some other input fields this checks if everything is filled in and if not it makes the inputfields red. if everything is correct it will create a table with the values of the inputfields i have filled in.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name="submit"]').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        formIsValid = true;

        var errors = [];
        $('.errors').html("");

        $('input.required').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                formIsValid = false;
                message = $(this).attr('id') + ' is required';
                errors.push(message);
                $(this).addClass("red");
            } else{
                $(this).removeClass("red");
            }
        });


        if (formIsValid == true) {
            $('.data').append('<tr class="datarow"><td>'+$('input[name="name"]').val()+'</td><td>'+$('input[name="email"]').val()+'</td><td>'+$('input[name="phone_number"]').val()+'</td><td class="delete">X</td></tr>');
            updateTotalRows();

            $('.delete').click(function() {
                $(this).parent().remove();
                updateTotalRows();
            })
        }
    });

    function updateTotalRows() {
        $('.total').html('Ik heb nu : ' + $('.datarow').length + ' rows');
    }
}); 
</script>

<script>
function selectCountry() {
    $('.data').append('<tr class="datarow"><td>'+$('.info_link').val()+'</td><td>'+'</td><td class="delete">X</td></tr>');
            updateTotalRows();  
}
</script>
```

I already have a clickable dropdown with country's in it but when i click it should use my function selectCountry. That function should make a table with the name of the subitem i have clicked.

Landen

Nederland

Duitsland

Frankrijk

```
<script>
$(".dropdown")
    .bind("click", function (selectCountry) {   
    console.log((selectCountry)) 
    });

</script>

<script>
$(function(){
 $('.info_link').click(function(){
 alert($(this).text());     //$('#table tr:last').append($("<td></td>").text());
                                });
            });
</script>
```

so my question is how do i make a clickable dropdown that takes the value of the subitem and puts it in a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a standard `<select id="mySelect"><option value="abc">ABC</option></select>` element and add a function on element value change:

```
$("#mySelect").change(function() {
  var optionValue = $(this).val();
  $('#table tr:last').append('<td>' + optionValue + '</td>');
});
```

Comment: im not sure on how to use that in my dropdown can you give me a hand here ?

Comment: put the code on a fiddle if possible. I also need to know what is `.dropdown`

Comment: .dropdown is the div claas of my dropdown menu  here is my fiddle fist one ever so probaly some mistakes: https://jsfiddle.net/ac4prp99/

Comment: Thanks for your help. Much appreciated